# Currency changes not works in email template if changed from cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email-templates, bundled-product

[image]

Can someone please help in finding out the right place where data is being fetched by Magento in order to make email template for `bundle items`. Here, the price for main bundle product is showing with correct currency and conversion but for the bundle items - only currency is correct and a price is showing in `INR`. The problem occurs only in the order email templates only. It is working fine everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The order items in a sales order email is rendered using the layout handle `<sales_email_order_items>` in `sales.xml`.

```
<sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

So you will need to check template file `email/order/items.phtml` and `email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

Comment: Already checked but here value is already prepared . I need to check where data is being fetched and prepared so that i can pull right data for bundle item's price.

Comment: how many stores are there in your magento?